# how to write a function doing this code

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

I've used this code to make and show a form in a MdiWindow:

```
        if (currentForm != null) {
            currentForm.Dispose();
        }
        currentForm = new ManageCompanies();
        currentForm.MdiParent = this;
        currentForm.Show();
        currentForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

I used this code to show about 20 different forms...

I want to write a such function:

```
private void ShowForm(formClassName) {

            if (currentForm != null) {
                currentForm.Dispose();
            }
            currentForm = new formClassName();
            currentForm.MdiParent = this;
            currentForm.Show();
            currentForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Do I have to send formClassName as a string or something else; and how to include it in the code...
I want the final code...

Comment: Select the whole code block and press Ctrl-K or just manually indent by 4 spaces.

Comment: Wisam, most of your questions are: "I want..." this website gives you help but do not take it for granted and please formulate your questions a bit better and politely, not just I want... ... give me the final code without any other effort required from me...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use MDI if you only ever allow *one* child window to be alive.

Comment: @Davide Piras, I appreciate your comment... and I'll take it in mind... and I think only this question and one another are of the kind you've mentioned... at next questions I'll formulate the questions better that this... to be useful as possible as can...

Comment: @Hans Passant, I am new to winforms dev... and I'm using MDI to keep a common tool-bar and menu-bar... and change the inner page... its like using master pages in asp.net...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try generics:

```
 public void ShowForm<FormClass>() where FormClass: Form,new() {

        if (currentForm != null) {
            currentForm.Dispose();
        }
        currentForm = new FormClass();
        currentForm.MdiParent = this;
        currentForm.Show();
        currentForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Or using reflection

```
public void ShowForm(string formClassName) {

        if (currentForm != null) {
            currentForm.Dispose();
        }
        currentForm = (Form) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(formClassName)) ;
        currentForm.MdiParent = this;
        currentForm.Show();
        currentForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is needed if it is `: Form`. I put it and then removed it.

Comment: It's not `where T` it's `where FormClass` because that's what you named your type variable.

Comment: @Aliostad, how otherwise he would access `MdiParent, Show() and WindowState`?

Comment: what do you mean by `won't hurt`, your code will not be compilable without it, it really hurts :)

Comment: @Aliostad: When you rename the type variable from `T` you also have to use that new name in your `where` specification. I've fixed it here for you, but please be careful in the future. :)

Comment: That's why we're pointing out compile errors. We are a squad of specially trained monkeys who can compile code without VS.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to specify:

```
private void ShowForm<FormClass> where T : Form, new() {
```

Note the new() on there so you can default construct the FormClass, otherwise it won't let you construct it.